# Rails: restrict POST request while loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, request

Hi srry if the title does not sound very descriptive, currently Im having a seriuos problem in my rails app, it's a clasifieds app, so users can create clasified ads, so the problem is that when an user tries to create a clasified, some times it loads some seconds due to the high volume of traffic, there are some impatient users that click the "Create" button in the form many times, the result: user created the same clasified ad many times, I mean, while user is waiting, if he clicks the create button again that creates a new POST request, so that's why the clasified is created many times. I do not know how to solve this problem, any idea?

**UPDATE**
I would like to implement a server-side solution, instead of front-end, I mean is there a way to validate this through the controller? or the view itself? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is use the `data-disabled-with` attribute in all the buttons, this will work for you:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Wait please..." } %>
```

This way everytime a button is clicked it will be disabled preventing double submission and also it will display the text "Wait please..."

Be careful in case you are using client-side validations in your form. in such cases you will have to remove the `disabled`attribute manually otherwise your button will stay disabled.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this similar issue...there are two reliable solutions for preventing multiple submission of forms:-

1. use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler from jquery which allows to be triggered only one time

   for example

   ```
   $("#post_submit_button").one("click", function(){
      //run ajax call and use .done and .error notify user
   });
   ```
2. other option is to use awesome [jqeury.validate js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) library to use live validation without submitting the form and when all values are valid,submit and disable the button.

for example

```
$("form#imageupload").validate({
        rules: {
        "image[title]": {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 3,
                  maxlength: 100
                }, 
                 submitHandler: function(form) {
                    //disable the button
                   $('#post_button').attr('disabled','disabled');
                   var formData = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax(
                 })
                  .done(function (response) {
                      if (response.success == 'success') {               
                          //alert('success');    

                      } else {
                          //alert('fail');
                                             }
                  }).error(function(data) {
                    //this will run when no server,or ajax cannot go forward
                          $('#post_button').removeAttr('disabled');

                  });
             return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax

        }
```

Comment: very nice answer, I will try it, however I will wait more suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Specify [disable_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) option for your submit button. It should partially solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I would have the function that handles your POST function return a redirect to a page identical to the one with the "create" button, only with the button inactive